# How to obtain an ArrayList from ArrayList.subList?

Tags: java, arraylist, sublist

I have an arraylist of a deck of cards ints 1-52 and they're shuffled and i'd like to basically split the deck in half indexes(0,25) and (26,51) to deal to two players. But I'm only seeing responses that say use List<> although I'd like to keep each players deck an arraylist as to not interfere with other already created methods. Is there a way to keep both players decks as arraylists?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Methods {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> deck =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static ArrayList<Integer> deckPlayerOne =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static ArrayList<Integer> deckPLayerTwo =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public static ArrayList<Integer> generateDeck(){
        for(int i=1; i<53; i++){
             deck.add(i);
        }
        return deck;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> shuffle(){
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
        return deck;
    }

    public static void splitDeck(){
        // deckPlayerOne = deck.subList(0, 25); <---- location of error
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> playerOneDeck(){

        }

    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> platerTwoDeck(){

    }
}
```

Comment: First, *what* error are you getting?  Second, all you really need as far as the contract for `List` is concerned is each one of your static methods to be a `List<Integer>` instead of an `ArrayList<Integer>`.  (They have to be newed in the way you're doing it now, though.)  Ultimately, if the contract for `List` is fulfilled, why do you care what the concrete implementation is?  I say this since there *may* be a reason you would care, but it's not apparent to me yet.

Comment: Declaring your variables or fields as `ArrayList` instead of `List` or `Collection` is bad practice.

Comment: Theoretically if I did want to directly go from ArrayList to ArrayList I'm guessing I'd have to copy and remove? from 25++ or x++?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand your question, but if you want an ArrayList to be split into other two you can use this:

```
    ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList part1 = new ArrayList(myArrayList.subList(0, 25));
    ArrayList part2 = new ArrayList(myArrayList.subList(26, 51));
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: I'm either told to cast deck or change deckPlayerOne to List<>

Comment: Alright it seems to be the most ideal answer, thanks.